# aplicación c# no se ejecuta

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2017, windows7

he desarrollado una aplicación C# - Visual Studio 2017 en Windows 10 de 64 bits. Al momento de instalar la aplicación en un computador cliente Windows 7 de 64 bits, lo instala perfectamente pero no abre el programa, me sale el siguiente error que se muestra en la foto.

Este es el error completo:

Firma con problemas:
  Nombre del evento de problema:    CLR20r3
  Firma del problema 01:    c.exe
  Firma del problema 02:    1.0.0.0
  Firma del problema 03:    9824fb87
  Firma del problema 04:    mscorlib
  Firma del problema 05:    4.7.3062.0
  Firma del problema 06:    5ab95381
  Firma del problema 07:    2d50
  Firma del problema 08:    2f
  Firma del problema 09:    System.ArgumentException
  Versión del sistema operativo:    6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Id. de configuración regional:    9226
  Información adicional 1:  7598
  Información adicional 2:  75981ec03177ed13808f21220cbc4863
  Información adicional 3:  da25
  Información adicional 4:  da250f58f4173d181af977d8ef196301

Aquí el proyecto completo: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fKbeKTqXd1sTpjj16OV2D9MrsUGteEDQ

Dentro de los archivos para agregar al instalador están todos agregados.

Aquí se muestra que la aplicación instala
[image: Aquí se muestra que la aplicación instala]

[image: Este es el error que me muestra al intentar abrir la aplicación]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Como creaste el paquete de instalacion? en los preriquisitos debes incluir las librerias para que no las descargue sino que las instale directamente si son necesarias.   ejemplo : Prerrequisitos> Chose to include .NET framework.

Comment: Puedes editar tu pregunta y compartir un pantallazo de la configuración de la publicación

Comment: @BrianVelez listo

Comment: algo veo raro en las captura de imagenes, porque el Visual Studio parace estar siendo accedido en una pc con TeamViewer? o sea estas remoto en otra pc. Como prerequisitos marcas para que se instale la version correcta del net framework

Comment: @LeandroTuttini, estoy desde el computador del cliente accediendo a mi pc donde desarrolle la aplicación para crear varios instaladores para ver si alguno funciona. Los pre-requisitos están todos marcados.

Comment: no intentaste definir un control de errores global, para ver si captura el problema, para esto debes controlar el evento `Application.ThreadException`  https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception?view=netframework-4.5